# Azure, making copy of linux VM without deleting the original

Tags: linux, azure, copy, clone

I have one Linux VM running in Azure, server1.

There are some things that I would like to test but I do not wan't to test those with server1. Server1 has applications and database that I need for the test so I would like to take copy of server1 and test with the copy (server2).

Is it possible to take copy of the server1 without deleting or "sysprepping" it?

Comment: Please post this to ServerFault, as this isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the VHD from your storage account and then use that with Hyper-V or create a VM using the copied VHD. This blog post has information on how to do that: http://michaelwasham.com/windows-azure-powershell-reference-guide/uploading-and-downloading-vhds-to-windows-azure/